# Multiprogramming in Unix

Tags: unix

I have some problems trying to make a simple program using execlp, fork and pipes.
The program at hand is supossed to do "last |head -5| sort" but it doesn't work. Here is the code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//last |head -5| sort
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

 int buzon[2];
 int buzon2[2];

 if(pipe(buzon) < 0)
  error("error de pipe");

 switch(fork()){

  case -1:
   error("error de fork");

  case 0:
   if(close(1) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(dup(buzon[1]) < 0) error("error de dup");
   if(close(buzon[0]) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(close(buzon[1]) < 0) error("error de close");
   execlp("last", "last", NULL);
   error("error de execlp");

 }



 switch(fork()){

  case -1:
   error("error de fork");

  case 0:
   if(close(0) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(close(1) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(dup(buzon[0]) < 0) error("error de dup");
   if(dup(buzon[1]) < 0) error("error de dup");
   if(close(buzon[0]) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(close(buzon[1]) < 0) error("error de close");
   execlp("head", "head", "-n 5", NULL);
   error("error de execlp");


 }


 switch(fork()){
  case -1: 
   error("error de fork");
  case 0:
   if(close(0)<0) error("error de close");
   if(dup(buzon[0]) != 1) error("error de dup");
   if(close(buzon[0]) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(close(buzon[1]) < 0) error("error de close");
   execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
   error("error de execlp");
 }


 if(close(buzon[0]) < 0) error("error de close");
 if(close(buzon[1]) < 0) error("error de close");
 while(wait(NULL) != -1);





}
```

Any idea of what fails. The problem is when I use 2 pipes. If I make a program which only uses 1 pipe, it works.

Comment: Do you have the error messages or errno numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create the second pipe, then use that for the stdout of the `head` process and the stdin of the `sort` process.  At the point of your second `fork()`:

```
 close(buzon[1]);
 pipe(buzon2);

 /* Now buzon[0], buzon2[0] and buzon2[1] are still open in this process */

 switch(fork()){

  case -1:
   error("error de fork");

  case 0:
   if(close(0) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(close(1) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(dup(buzon[0]) < 0) error("error de dup");
   if(dup(buzon2[1]) < 0) error("error de dup");
   if(close(buzon[0]) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(close(buzon2[0]) < 0) error("error de close");
   if(close(buzon2[1]) < 0) error("error de close");
   execlp("head", "head", "-n 5", NULL);
   error("error de execlp");
   exit(1);
 }

 close(buzon[0]);
 close(buzon2[1]);
 /* Now buzon2[0] is still open in this process */

 switch(fork()){
  case -1: 
   error("error de fork");
  case 0:
   if(close(0)<0) error("error de close");
   if(dup(buzon2[0]) < 0) error("error de dup");
   if(close(buzon2[0]) < 0) error("error de close");
   execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
   error("error de execlp");
   exit(1);
 }

 close(buzon2[0]);
```

(You should also `exit()` the child process after an `execlp()` error)

Comment: After doing that, it gives me the following error when executing:

Head: writing error: invalid file descriptor.

Any idea?

Comment: @olbrich: It works fine for me - perhaps you didn't get all the changes (are you calling `dup()` on now `buzon2[1]` in the `head` path, rather than `buzon[1]`?)

Comment: it works fine now, I confused buzon2[1] with buzon[1] in the dup(). Thank you very much!